# How to handle the recyclerview's items view inside activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my app's recyclerview, each item have Play/Pause button to start/stop the media player. There are many events like downloading progress, play and stop the music.  I'm going handle the events and update the UI immediately with broadcast receiver or in another way. 
I do not know ho to access play or pause button in the activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

        holder.downloading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.equalizer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                      holder.btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btnPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

     public  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageButton btnPlay, btnPause;
        TextView title, id;
        private ImageView trackImage, downloaded;
        private GifImageView equalizer, downloading;
        private CardView cardView;


  public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

            equalizer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eq);
            downloading = itemView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
            btnPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play);
            btnPause = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pause);


            btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MyOnClickListener.playOnClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MyOnClickListener.pauseOnClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

        }
```

and inside activity, here how i can access to *btnPlay*, *btnPause*, ,... to set them visible or invisible in specefic times:

```
 adapter = new Adapter(tracks, this, new Adapter.MyAdapterListener() {
        @Override
        public void playOnClick(View v, int position) {


            if (//true) {
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(currentItem, //?);
            } 

               // hide some views in recyclerview's item and show some others

            } else {
                //...
            }
}
```

**update:**

```
                for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
                Track track = tracks.get(i);
                if (track.getPlayStatus()) {
                    track.setPlayStatus(false);
                    //tell the RecyclerView this data position has changes
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Track track = tracks.get(position);
            track.setPlayStatus(true);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

and  *onBindViewHolder*:

```
if (track.getPlayStatus()) {
        holder.btnPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //other sets you need
    } else {
        holder.btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to access "Play" or "Pause" button in the activity?

Comment: for example if play button pressed then it should be invisible and pause bytton be visible and other stats like this.

Comment: You could do this solely inside your adapter if that's all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of current playing position to fix this.
The trick is to refresh both the currently playing view as well as new clicked view

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private int currentPlayingPosition = -1;
    private MyOnClickListener mMyOnClickListener;

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // return viewholder
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (position == currentPlayingPosition) {
            holder.btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // other bindings
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // return size
    }

    public void setMyOnClickListener(MyOnClickListener myOnClickListener) {
        mMyOnClickListener = myOnClickListener;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageButton btnPlay, btnPause;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // bind views

            btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    int prev = currentPlayingPosition;
                    currentPlayingPosition = position;

                    if (prev >= 0)
                        notifyItemChanged(prev);  // refresh previously playing view

                    notifyItemChanged(currentPlayingPosition);

                    mMyOnClickListener.playOnClick(v, position);
                }
            });

            btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                    currentPlayingPosition = -1;
                    mMyOnClickListener.pauseOnClick(v, position);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private interface MyOnClickListener {
        void playOnClick(View v, int position);

        void pauseOnClick(View v, int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass anything to your `Activity` if all you need is to change items of a specific row. 
Let's say your list item is clicked for playing. Then, you just set the corresponding `isPlaying` flag(please add it if it's not there yet) of your data item to `true` as below and notify the adapter there a change:

```
@Override
public void playOnClick(View v, int position) {
    // reset playing state for a previous track if only one item can be played at a time
    for (int i = 0; i < trackList.size(); i++) {
        Track track = trackList.get(i);
        if (track.isPlaying()) {
            track.setIsPlaying(false);
            //tell the RecyclerView this data position has changes
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
            break;
        }    
    } 

    Track track = trackList.get(position);
    track.setIsPlaying(true); 
    //initiate the RecyclerView redrawal
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Your `pauseOnClick` could be:

```
@Override
public void pauseOnClick(View v, int position) {
    Track track = trackList.get(position);
    track.setIsPlaying(false); 
    //initiate the RecyclerView redrawal
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position); 
}
```

In your `onBindViewHolder` you change the item visibility based on the adapter data you're passing:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Wkdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
    Track track = trackListList.get(position);
    if (track.isPlaying()) {
        holder.btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //other sets you need
    } else {
        holder.btnPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //your other inits
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but If another item"s start to play then the previus item shoul be update.

Comment: @Amirhosein I updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: @Amirhosein because you didn't put anything in the else block in onBindViewHolder. I updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your widgets as arguments to your `MyOnClickListener` functions, like below:

```
MyOnClickListener.playOnClick(v, btnPlay, getAdapterPosition());
```

Answer (score -1):

**try something like  this**

```
 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CardView oneway_card, CardView;
    private ImageView logo, arrow;
    private Context context;
    private List<Onwardflights> objectlist;

    private TextView arrival, departure, duration, amount, flightcode, arr_text, stops, stops_text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, List<Onwardflights> objectlist) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.context = context;
        this.objectlist = objectlist;

*Initialize here*
logo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.oneway_logo);
            arrival = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.oneway_arrtime);

}
```

**Your onclick method**

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        Log.i("Position", "Postion " + position + " is clicked");
        oneway_card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0FFFF"));

        //your code

    }
```